# Why I am getting undefined from the localStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, local-storage

I am trying to learn **firebase** by reading their documentation. I have added login using **google account** and **email password**. When I click on **log in**, I am dispatching **setLogInValue** and the state is updating but getting the value of **isLoggedIn**: **undefined**. But when I first visit the page the value of **isLoggedIn** is **null**. I expect the value of **isLoggedIn**: **true** after clicking on **log in** and redirect to homepage but as I am getting **undefined** the routing is not working.

**slice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  email: localStorage.getItem('email'),
  isLoggedIn: localStorage.getItem('loggedInStatus'),
};

export const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'slice',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setLogInValue: (state, action) => {
      state.email = localStorage.setItem('email', action.payload);
      state.isLoggedIn = localStorage.setItem('loggedInStatus', true);
    },
  },
});

export const { setLogInValue } = slice.actions;

export default slice.reducer;
```

**Login.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  getAuth,
  signInWithPopup,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setLogInValue } from '../redux/slice';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { auth } from '../firebase/firebase';

const Login = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState({ email: '', password: '' });

  const inputHandler = event => {
    setInput({ ...input, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // const auth = getAuth();
  const googleSignIn = () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then(result => {
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const token = credential.accessToken;
        // The signed-in user info.
        const user = result.user;
        dispatch(setLogInValue(user.email));
        // localStorage.setItem('loggedInStatus', true);
        navigate('/', { replace: true });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        const email = error.customData.email;
        // The AuthCredential type that was used.
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
        // ...
        console.log(errorMessage);
      });
  };

  const submitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // const auth = getAuth();
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, input.email, input.password)
      .then(userCredential => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log(user);
        dispatch(setLogInValue(input.email));

        setInput({
          email: '',
          password: '',
        });

        navigate('/', { replace: true });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorMessage);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form
        className="w-75 mx-auto mt-5"
        onSubmit={event => submitHandler(event)}>
        <div className="form-floating mb-3">
          <input
            name="email"
            type="email"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="name@example.com"
            value={input.email}
            onChange={inputHandler}
          />
          <label>Email address</label>
        </div>
        <div className="form-floating">
          <input
            name="password"
            type="password"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Password"
            value={input.password}
            onChange={inputHandler}
          />
          <label>Password</label>
        </div>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="btn btn-primary btn-lg d-block mx-auto mt-3">
          Log in
        </button>
      </form>
      <button
        className="btn btn-primary btn-lg d-block mx-auto mt-3"
        onClick={googleSignIn}>
        Log in With Google
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

**Home.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';
import { Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Nav from './components/Nav';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const App = () => {
  const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector(state => state.info);
  console.log('App:', isLoggedIn);

  let routes;
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    routes = (
      <>
        <Nav />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
        </Routes>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    routes = (
      <>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/login" replace />} />
        </Routes>
      </>
    );
  }

  return <>{routes}</>;
};

export default App;
```

**Nav.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light ">
      <div className="container">
        <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">
          Navbar
        </Link>
        <Link className="nav-link" to="/">
          Home
        </Link>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

Why I am getting **undefined** instead of "true/false/" of **isLoggedIn** value from the localStorage? How can I fix that?

Comment: Keep in mind that localStorage stores strings only. Also, you can press F12 to open the browser's dev tools and check the current values at any time. Did you do that yet? What exactly is stored there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the code in 'slice.js':

```
setLogInValue: (state, action) => {
  state.email = localStorage.setItem('email', action.payload);
  state.isLoggedIn = localStorage.setItem('loggedInStatus', true); // <<<< Problem here: function localStorage.setItem return 'undefined' value
},
```

so you should fix like this:

```
setLogInValue: (state, action) => {
  localStorage.setItem('loggedInStatus', true)
  localStorage.setItem('email', action.payload);

  state.email = action.payload;
  state.isLoggedIn = true;
},
```